# Logic behind the Inner Function

Tags: python, nested-function

I'm currently learning Python and following a tutorial and made it to decorators. But before diving there, i want to get a good grasp of how inner function works and I came across this piece of code.

```
def max(a, b, c):
    def max2(x, y):     
        return x if x >= y else y   
    return max2(a, max2(b, c))

main_max = max(15, 5, 10)

print(main_max)
```

Now, I'm trying to understand the logic behind it, but I can't seem to understand the sequence of passing the arguments. I ran it on debug mode and did the lines step-by-step and what I noticed was x is being assigned the value of b and y is being assigned the value of c. Why is that?

Is it because the second argument which is max2(b, c) is being evaluated first before evaluating max2(a, max2(b, c)) ?

Comment: Do note that `max` as defined here shadows the built-in method [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max). This may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I just copied the code from another post that gave an example on how inner/nested function works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Max takes three arguments. Max2 takes two arguments. The only relevant line of code is

```
return max2(a, max2(b, c))
```

We know that `a` is `a`. In order to continue the computation we need to resolve (using `max2`) the greater of `b` or `c`. In other words, `max2(15, max2(5, 10))` can be thought of like

```
t = max2(5, 10) # (5 ? 10) = 10
return max2(15, t) # (15 ? 10) = 15
```

The only other thing to realize is that the scope of `max2` is being limited to within `max`.

Comment: 'The only relevant code' answered it all.Thank you for the explanation.